# Angular remove locationStrategyListener on ngDestroy

Tags: angular, event-listener, browser-history

I am wondering why my problem seems to be so non-trivial: As we have implemented server side querying, pagination, etc. we need to request our API whenever the user makes changes in the table (e.g. when querying for name=x the client sends a request with corresponding query parameters to the backend). This also means that we need to request the backend when going back in history, specifically when clicking the back button of the browser.

This works fine with the following code:

```
constructor(private locationStrategy: LocationStrategy) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.locationStrategy.onPopState(() => {
        this.refreshHistory();
    })
}
```

However, since in every initialization of the component we add a new listener to listen to the history event, we are quickly sending hundreds of equal requests to the backend (since each listener invokes the `refreshHistory()` method).

I somehow need to remove any eventListener in the `ngDestroy` interface, but `locationStrategy` does not seem to provide such a feature. Is there any (clean) way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Please correct me if this is a totally wrong approach. I am more used to implement backends than frontends.

Comment: how are your routes set up? I wouldn't expect to need to re-initialize the component every time you search.

Comment: We are not reinitializing the component with every search, we are just sending a request to the backend whenever a column has been sorted or a filter has been queried. The multiple listeners result from navigating to other components, e.g. when the user clicks in another element in the navbar and then comes back to this component. It's obvious that this side effects results from not deleting the event listener in the ngOnDestroy method.

Comment: ah sorry, i misread the question. are you creating the query based on queryParameters from the current url? i mean when a user sorts or filters the table in the ui, does that update query params in the url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution for this is actually pretty easy once one read through the heck of RxJS documentation.
We use its `fromEvent` operator to create a subscription of the onPopState event. From this subscription we can easily unsubscribe and everything works like a charm.

```
import {fromEvent, Subscription} from "rxjs";

export class CommentAllComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private backEvent: Subscription;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.backEvent = fromEvent(window, 'popstate').subscribe(() => {
        // doCustomRefresh()
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.backEvent.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Alternate Approach

Instead of using LocationStrategy, I would suggest that you take a look at using the queryParams of the route. You can subscribe to them in `ngOnInit`, and unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy`. It seems like it would work well in your case where you are basically trying to navigate back to a previous state in a component.

For example a user might click back from here:

localhost:4200/#/table?filterString=foo&colSort=idAscending

And end up here:

localhost:4200/#/table?filterString=foo

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  paramSub: Subscription;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.paramSub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params); // query params changed, getData()
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.paramSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

In addition to the angular docs, I found this article helpful for getting started with QueryParams https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/

### Extra

The problem with LocationStrategy is, as you've noted, there isn't a provided way to remove a listener.

I dont know enough to say whether it's impossible to continue this approach, but it's certainly more complex. You could try using a named function, instead of an anonymous function like so:

```
  constructor(private location: LocationStrategy) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.location.onPopState(this.popStateHandler);
  }

  popStateHandler(event){
    console.log('handle onPopState', event);
  }
```

It seems like step in the right direction in that it solves the issue of registering a new handler function every time you initialize the component. But then the problem becomes the fact that every time you click back regardless of where you are in the app, the handler function will fire.

Comment: Thanks! This should work, but it comes with a logic overhead, because you must differentiate between a normal component visit (e.g. coming from navbar to it) and a history change. We are using a framework (clarity) at which we hook in its refresh method with our custom logic. This means we do not have influence on when the refresh method is called (as this is framework, not custom program flow). Therefore I would need to add the additional logic to check the reason of the url change. I came up with another solution.